# Redirect every URL to new domain, including subdomains (via htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

I'm doing a website migration and need to redirect all URLs, including subdomains, to the new root domain.
So, for example:

- old-domain.nl/example => https://www.new-domain.nl
- [www.old-domain.nl/example](http://www.old-domain.nl/example) => https://www.new-domain.nl
- http://www.old-domain.nl/example => https://www.new-domain.nl

And also:

- subdomain.old-domain.nl/example => https://www.new-domain.nl
- anothersubdomain.old-domain.nl => https://www.new-domain.nl

This is what I got so far, but sadly it is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.old-domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new-domain.nl/ [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be great :D !

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work :(
Notice that the htaccess file is in the root directory and need to catch all subdomains.

Comment: Why shouldn't that work? The issue is not that the rewriting does not work, but that you apparently map those sub domains (actually http hosts) to different parts of your file system. So just change that, make them all point to the same folder where you implement that rule.

Comment: Even better is to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration instead of using a distributed configuration file.

Comment: And you should use a negated condition: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.new-domain\.nl$` ...